# Unit testing for ClassMethod of a model in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two databases: one is `master` and for testing, I have another database `master_test`

To retrieve a total price from a table I have created a `@classmethod` in a model. This method helps me get the sum of the price filtering by month and year. Here is the class method:

```
@classmethod
def get_total_book_price(cls, id):

    query = Book.query.with_entities(
        func.sum(Book.price).label("price")
    ).filter(
        extract('year', Book.created_at) >= datetime.date.today().year,
        extract('month', Book.created_at) >= datetime.date.today().month
    ).filter(
        Book.id == id
    ).all()

    return query[0].price
```

This query works nicely. But when I run this for test case its showing `master` database does not exist. It should find the `master_test` database instead of the `master` database.
Here is the test code:

```
def test_get_total_book_price(self):
    id = 1
    response = Book.get_total_book_price(id)
    if not response:
        self.assertEqual(response, False)
    self.assertEqual(response, True)
```

It's showing the ERROR:

```
 sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  database "master" 
 does not exist
 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Ran 34 tests in 2.011s
 FAILED (errors=1)
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Some other test cases are working nicely with `master_test`. But for this test why it is looking for `master` database ?

Comment: How does the code you show know about any database in the first place? Presumably that's baked into `Book` somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide a context for your test function. The best way to do this is with factories. An excellent description how to do this is: http://alanpryorjr.com/2019-05-20-flask-api-example/ . If you have an app and a db fixture, you can just use it in your test function:

```
from test.fixtures import app, db

def test_get_total_book_price(self, db):
    id = 1
    response = Book.get_total_book_price(id)
    if not response:
        self.assertEqual(response, False)
    self.assertEqual(response, True)
```

Yes, the only difference is the **db** in the function call. I cannot say why your other tests are working. My best guess is that your failing test is executed after the test context is destroyed. Better be explicit about your app context every single time.

If everything else fails (and you have access to your app with the right database connection) you could push the context manually with:

```
from foo import app

def test_get_total_book_price(self, app):
    app.app_context().push()        
    id = 1
    response = Book.get_total_book_price(id)
    if not response:
        self.assertEqual(response, False)
    self.assertEqual(response, True)
```

I want to stress that you should use factories for your testing.

Reference: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/appcontext/